# Authenticode code-signing incredibly slow

Tags: clickonce, code-signing, xbap

We have a utility we created to sign our XBAP manifest file.  This is the following code that it executes:

```
cert = new X509Certificate2(certFilePath, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
SecurityUtilities.SignFile(cert, null, manifest.SourcePath);
```

The SignFile method takes more than two minutes to complete.  We previously used a Thawte authenticode certificate to sign our manifest.  After switching to VeriSign, this issue started appeared.  Also, when Visual Studio signs the XBAP manifest during the build process, it usually takes between seven and nine minutes to complete.

I've tried putting the private key in the local computer store.  I've tried putting the intermediate VeriSign code-signing certificate in the intermediate certificate authorities store.

Has anyone experienced this before and/or have ideas as to how to remedy the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe my issue is caused by the lack of internet access on the server that is executing this code.  Using a packet analyzer I noticed that during signing the application and/or Windows is trying to access VeriSign's [certificate revocation lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revocation_list) (CRLs) and it's [Online Certificate status Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Certificate_Status_Protocol) (OCSP).  These actions are timing out.  This code signing was occurring more than once and therefore causing the delay to be longer.  Allowing access to VeriSign through the fire should fix this.

Answer (score 3):

I asked the ClickOnce guy at Microsoft about your question (even though it's not about C/O per se). He said if you are time-stamping the certificate, it might be trying to connect to a timestamp server and that might be slowing things down. You specify that in Visual Studio in one of the tabs for the project, and it is used at signing time.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you do need to install the certificate on the server in addition to having the internet connection and checking the CRL. We have a server that is having the similar problem. It was not taking one or tow minutes to execute the SignFile method, but it was taking 10 seconds for each call and was taking 20-30 seconds for it. After I installed the certificate, the method now takes about two hundredth of a seconds for each call...so, the two or three calls to the methods takes a fraction of a seconds.